# how to include html and js code into one single js file?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to include an iframe, that has to be responsive , with no scroll in multiple websites. I need to do that wih one line of code like this:

```
<script src="testfile.js"></script>
```

This is the html code that I have to somehow include in the testfile.js

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Seamless.js | Beautiful, seamless iframes.</title>
  <script src="../build/seamless.parent.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
      window.seamless(document.getElementById('childpage'), {
        fallbackText: 'Having Trouble?'
      });
    };
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row panel">
  <div class="large-12 columns">
    <iframe id="childpage" src="example1.child.html?id=###"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I could only use the iframe part in order to have one single line of code:

```
 <iframe id="childpage" src="example1.child.html?id=###"></iframe>
```

but i need the extra html and js, in order to have the iframe responsive and with adjustable width

Comment: You cannot edit the Javascript that resides inside your `iframe`. If you want you need to add the Javascript inside `example1.child.html` file. There is no way to control the responsiveness of the content **inside** your `iframe`.

Comment: Usually HTML is stored in a html file (or in your case for example in a PHP file), and JS is stored in a JS file ...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use HTML code inside your js explicitly, To edit the properties of your html tags you can do the following.
Just use getElementsByTagName("iframe").style to fetch all the CSS refrences for iframes in your HTML page and you can accordingly set them.

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Seamless.js | Beautiful, seamless iframes.</title>
  <script src="../build/seamless.parent.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
      window.seamless(document.getElementById('childpage'), {
        fallbackText: 'Having Trouble?'
      });
    };
  </script>
  <script src="testfile.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="myFunction()">
<div class="row panel">
  <div class="large-12 columns">
    <iframe id="childpage" src="example1.child.html?id=###"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**testfile.js**

```
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("iframe").style.overflow="hidden";
}
```

Respond in the thread if it worked.